# How to modularize the code for JsonObject and JsonArray to read Json files at class level. Which I am using later to write Testcases

Tags: java, gson, cucumber-jvm

I am using GSON library to read JSON file for my automation. For which I need to read file and then create a object of json while traversing the JSON.

Later I am using these objects to to modify the JSON..
I want to reduce the code for traversing down the json as many objects are getting created.

Though this works perfectly fine. Just I need to modularize the code.

**Adding the code with the URL , Response and User JSON**

**Url.json**

```
{"emplyee":
{"addemplyee": "<URL>/emplyee","addemplyee": "<URL>/editemplyee"}
}
```

**Response .json**

```
[
{"success":true},
{"success":false}
]
```

**emplyee.json**

```
{

"addemplyee":
{"details":{  
  "lst":"lastname",
  "id":"username",
  "Password":"password"
}
},
"editemplyee":

{ "details":{  
 "Password":"password"
}}}
```

**Actual**
Currently I am creating multiple objects to read ths jOSN file and later with the use of same I am updating my JSON.

**Expected**
Can I modularize this approach of code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
public static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); //you can reuse gson as often as you like

public <T> static T readJson(String file){
try{
FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(file)); //gson takes a filereader no need to load the string to ram
T t = GSON.fromJson(fr, T.getClass());
fr.close(); //close the reader
return t;
}catch(Error e){
//ignore or print, if you need
}
}
```